# How do I make a list of the same variable with different values? python

Tags: python, list, append

I am a complete newbie and this might be a dumb question:
I need to make a list of the values as u can see down here.
I will most likely need a for loop using append from what I have read till now but I cant really grasp how to do it in my case.
I want to start with the min value 23 and increment by 2 until I reach the max 31
And I would need to be able to change the values in the for loop for future changes
The +3 has to be added everytime regardless
It would be great if someone could help me.

```
arrivalDistance = meanSpeed * (23 + 3)
arrivalDistance2 = meanSpeed * (25 + 3)
arrivalDistance3 = meanSpeed * (27 + 3)
arrivalDistance4 = meanSpeed * (29 + 3)
arrivalDistance5 = meanSpeed * (31 + 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of evaluating the `+ 3` and `+ 23` at each variable, you can use a loop, and directly add the numbers to the parameters of the loop:

```
a = 23 + 3
b = 5
step = 2
arrivalDistance = [meanSpeed * i for i in range(a, a + b * step, step)]
```

So `a` is the starting value, `b` is the additional value, `c` is the number of variables and `step` is the increment amount.

Comment: wouldnt the end value    a + b * step   also need to have a +1 for the syntax to be correct? or what am I missing?

Comment: @NyamEnkhbaatar Oh, the 3 is already added to the a when it's being defined. Though you have a point; it's better not to hard code that. I'll edit it.

Comment: @NyamEnkhbaatar Oh, sorry again, I just realized that the syntax is currently correct ^^"

Answer (score 3):

```
arrivalDistance = [meanSpeed * (23+i +3) for i in range(0, 9, 2)]
```

This will create a list called `arrivalDistance` that will loop over the range `[0, 9)` with a step of 2. So it will get you the numbers `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` and add them to your value. This is called **list comprehension** and lets you avoid using a `for loop`, since it's already one.

Comment: I think this is what u call a very elegant solution. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @NyamEnkhbaatar You're welcome. If I helped you then please click the `tick` mark under the vote counter, it helps me a lot :)

Comment: ah okay I did that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
arrivalDistanceList = []

for i in range(23,32,2):
    arrivalDistanceList.append(meanSpeed * (i + 3))
```

The syntax of for loop

```
for iterator in range(startValue, endValue + 1, increment)
```

The third parameter is increment which increment the sequence by given value.

Hope you got the answer

Comment: Thank you seeing different solutions so fast is amazing!